# I am getting below error while invoking cypress using command Cypress Open from the location

Tags: cypress

Steps :

1-- npm install cypress --save-dev
2-- \node_modules.bin>cypress open

**Message:** EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'D:\newProCypress\node_modules.bin\cypress'

**Stack trace:**

```
[object Object]
    at fn (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:88145:14)
    at ipcBus (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:88164:10)
    at Object.ipc.<computed> [as openProject] (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:88205:69)
    at Object.openProject (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:90620:67)
    at Project.componentDidMount (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:90201:78)
    at ik (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75003:360)
    at ../../node_modules/react-dom/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.production.min.js.exports.unstable_runWithPriority (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75103:437)
    at fg (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:74872:325)
    at Yj (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:74996:437)
    at Lj (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:74975:420)
    at file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:74873:115
    at ../../node_modules/react-dom/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.production.min.js.exports.unstable_runWithPriority (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75103:437)
    at fg (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:74872:325)
    at ig (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:74873:61)
    at jg (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:74872:496)
    at bk (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:74976:156)
    at reactionScheduler (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:48544:47)
    at runReactions (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:48520:5)
    at endBatch (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:48220:9)
From previous event:
    at App.componentDidMount (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:86166:77)
    at ik (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75003:360)
    at ../../node_modules/react-dom/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.production.min.js.exports.unstable_runWithPriority (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75103:437)
    at fg (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:74872:325)
    at Yj (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:74996:437)
    at Lj (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:74975:420)
    at Rg (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:74966:137)
    at rk (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75031:43)
    at file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75034:301
    at ck (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:74976:210)
    at zk (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75034:287)
    at render (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75038:416)
    at Object.start (file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:88777:61)
    at file:///C:/Users/u65557/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.5.0/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/index.html:29:11
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem.

When you run Cypress for the first time your terminal should not be in the `node_modules\.bin` directory.

When you run Cypress for the first time, it will try to create a `cypress` file in the current directory (which will contain differents files like test examples). This name is already used in the `node_modules\.bin` directory. That's why you encounter this error.

I therefore recommend that you move to the parent directory of `node_modules` using `cd ..\..` then use `npx cypress open`. This should allow you to launch Cypress like for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project root and do

```
node_modules\.bin\cypress open
```

or

```
npx cypress open
```

or create npm script in `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "open": "cypress open"
  }
```

and run

```
npm run open
```

or install yarn and run

```
yarn cypress open
```